# How to create a one to many relationship betwee users and sessions where user is on one's side and session on many's side?

Tags: python, django, session

Hi I am creating a django application where I wanted to save some dictionaries for each log in session of a user.I am saving these dictionaries in django Sessions. Now I need to associate these sessions with the user like the following. When the user logs in  a list of his past sessions should be shown and he can either select to load one of them or create a new session. When he logs out he is asked whether save current session or not. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: use [foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Comment: Are you using django's builtin session framework? If so, each Session has an `_auth_user_id` key pointing to the User.

Comment: Hi, I just checked request.session['_auth_user_id'] returning 1. Is it the primary key of that user?

Comment: Hi, I just checked `request.session['_auth_user_id']` returning 1 and I have only one user. Is it the primary key of that user?